# Reference Type Value-Returning vs Void (NonValue-Returning) functions

Tags: c#

I am working on Reference Type vs Value Type.

Is there a difference between value-returning and void functions of reference type
example FooSb vs FooSb2  Memory Address, Memory Type, Code Quality,Design Pattern etc.

> Edit :  StringBuilder is just sample of reference type object

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StringBuilder sb;
        Stopwatch stopwatch;
        Foo foo = new Foo();

        Console.WriteLine($"BEFORE : {1}"); // 1

        sb = new StringBuilder("1");
        stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        stopwatch.Start();
        foo.FooSb(sb);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"AFTER FooSb : {sb.ToString()}\t{stopwatch.Elapsed}"); // -1

        sb = new StringBuilder("1");
        stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        sb = foo.FooSb2(sb);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"AFTER FooSb2 : {sb.ToString()}\t{stopwatch.Elapsed}"); // -1


        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public void FooSb(StringBuilder sb)
        {
            sb.Clear().Append("-1");
        }
        public StringBuilder FooSb2(StringBuilder sb)
        {
            return sb.Clear().Append("-1");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
 - BEFORE       :  1 
 - AFTER FooSb  : -1       00:00:00.0001358 
 - AFTER FooSb2 : -1       00:00:00.0000971
```

> **For example :**
>
> I have a reference type object. I will change value of the
>   object using another function. Value will change with function whether
>   use return or not. Why should i use return ?

Comment: `void` means there's no return value. The two methods don't do the same thing. What is the actual question?

Comment: You can chain `FooSb2`, e.g. `StringBuilder result = MyFoo.FooSb2(myBuilder).Append("abc");`

Comment: my quesition is not void or not void funciton. if we need reference type parametre why should use return.

Comment: If the *actual* question is `would I get a performance penalty from chaining methods?` the answer would be `no`. After all, `Clear()` and `Append()` already return the original StringBuilder instance

Comment: `if we need reference type parametre why should use return.`what does that mean? If you want to return a value, don't use `void`. If you *don't* want to return a value, use `void`. This has nothing to do with parameters

Comment: If the actual question is `why does 'FooSb2' return the StringBuilder?` the answer is to enable call chaining the same way `Clear()` and `Append()` do. You can write `foo.FooSb2(sb).AppendLine("xyz").AppendFormat("{0} "{1}",1,2).ToString()`

Comment: for example I have a reference type object. I will change value of the object using another function. Value will change with function whether use return or void . Why should i use return ?

Comment: StringBuilder that just is example of reference type. It can another class

Comment: The compiler uses the microprocessor register ax for the return value of a method.  When a method has a void the compiler skip reading the ax register of the microprocessor in the compiled code.

Comment: Anybody would expect FooSb2() to create a new StringBuilder object and not modify the passed-in object.  Which is an entirely valid stylistic choice, but of course as-is it is going to give any programmer a huge surprise.  That FooSb() modifies the passed object isn't that pretty either, picking the right name for the method is very important.  Something resembling "Replace" would give the right kind of usage hint.

Comment: @jdweng i agree ,Probably FooSb() function better performance than FooSb2()

Comment: You are definitely measuring time intervals wrong. `Stopwatch.StartNew()` returns alredy running stopwatch, so the first interval you measure includes more operations than the second.

Comment: In fact, the whole benchmark is not trustable. I recommend you to check out BenchmarkDotNet library for benchmarks you can trust. Regarding your actual results: when you're benchmarking roughly the same code, first time it'll take longer, because it has to JIT. BenchmarkDotNet takes that into account by warming the code prior to running actual benchmark. It takes care of that, and countless other nuances of proper benchmarking.

Comment: @omansak like kalexi said you should preform some kind of warm up before the benchmark, and should not trust the result of the single measurement you made

Comment: Why would performance be any different.  One read instruction of the micro is not measurable.  The timer accuracy is one tick (100nsec) and the read is much less than the tick.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is why you would return the StringBuilder as in FooSb2, as others stated in the comments, this is so that you can chain functions.

As far as performance goes, the difference would likely be negligible. Choosing void vs return has nothing to do with performance. Rather, by opting to return instead of using void, you can make it easier to use the class.

In fact, StringBuilder itself follows this pattern. The StringBuilder's Append method returns an instance of itself. It's function definition is something similar to:

```
public StringBuilder Append(string str)
{
    // append logic, etc.
    return this;
}
```

Thus, this allows you to this:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder("1").Append("2").Append("3");
```

If the Append method returned void, you would have to do this instead:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("1");
sb.Append("2");
sb.Append("3");
```

In the example you provided, however, it wouldn't make much sense to use FooSb2.

```
public class Foo
{
    public void FooSb(StringBuilder sb)
    {
        sb.Clear().Append("-1");
    }
    public StringBuilder FooSb2(StringBuilder sb)
    {
        return sb.Clear().Append("-1");
    }
}
```

If you were to "chain" FooSb2, you would have to do:

```
FooSb2(FooSb2(FooSb2(sb)))
```

So in that particular case, I can't see any benefit in returning the StringBuilder. Void would be more appropriate.